# Avoiding Redirects for Users Who Have Already Visite

Tags: javascript, cookies, overriding

My website has a script which redirects users to a landing page with prompts to download our app or return to the desktop site. However, when they hit "Desktop" from their mobile phones, it will loop them back to the landing page. Is there a way to override this once someone has visited the page?

Our website is www.hotshotsnet.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the idea is simple:

- You check the cookie "alreadyseen" for 1 in your homepage. If it's not there - redirect to landing page.
- once the user hits "desktop" you set the previously mentioned cookie with 1 and get him to your homepage

So now everyone that hasn't clicked "desktop" before will be redirected to landing page. And everyone who did will not have to see it again.

Also don't forget to set expire time and path when setting the cookie.

Comment: Now, how does one add that to a script. I'm code illiterate.

Comment: Just google for setting and getting cookies using javascript. You'll get tons of samples and helper functions. I'm on a mobile app so it's difficult to "code".

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)hotshotsmobile\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
  document.location = "http://www.hotshotsnet.com/";
  document.cookie = hotshotsmobile=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
} else {
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "http://www.hotshotsnet.com/portals/0/mobile/mobile.html";
}
}
</script>

Comment: I added a cookie (hotshotsmobile) to the mobile.html page and then added the above script to the main page, but it's not working. Any advice?

Comment: That's far too complicated. All you need is make the "algorithm" I described work using javascript and cookies. Read more about setting/reading them here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I didn't really get what you were alluding to, but figured it out on my own by doing a little more research. Thanks, anyway.